# Have I done this group proof correctly?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

> Show that $G$ under multiplication, where $G=\{ x+y|x,y\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $x,y$ are not simultaneously zero, is a group.

Here's my take to it:

We show that $G\leq (\mathbb{R}, \cdot)$

$\forall a,b \in G$ we have

$ab^{-1}=(x_1+y_1)(x_2+y_2)^{-1}=\frac{x_1+y_1}{x_2+y_2} \in G$.

Therefore, $G$ is a group under multiplication.

Comment: You can't show that $G$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}, \cdot)$ because the latter isn't a group to begin with.

Comment: Are you sure about the definition of $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: @Randall oh well... I guess I didn't think that through.

Answer (score 5):

As it is defined in your question, $G$ is not a group. Letting $x=1$ and $y=-1$ gives $x,y\in\mathbb Q$ not simultaneously zero, and $x+y=0$. This means that $0\in G$, but $0$ has no multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb Q$, so this cannot be a group under multiplication at all.